# CSS, HTML & DIV IDs

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a sample webpage, but the results aren't coming along as I'd planned. What's supposed to happen is a black rectangular header box is supposed to show. I'll give you the sample code.

**HTML CODE / learningcss.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link href="div.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>CSS Tutorial 1</title>
</head>

<p>
We are creating this page to see how to make a better looking website.
</p>

<p>
We are creating this page to see how to make a better looking website.
</p>

<div id="header">
This is a paragraph
</div id="header">

<body>

<div id="column 2">
<h1>The Header</h1>
</div>

<div id="Column 2">
This is a basic CSS<br>
<br>
Tokyo<br>
</div>

<div id="Column 3">
<h1><a href="<a href="http://gymforgeeks.userecho.com/http://gymforgeeks.userecho.com/">
This is GymForGeeks
</h1>
<p>
This is just a sample page using CSS.
</p>
<p>
Yet another sample text content.
</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
Copyright Queensborough 
</div>

</body>
<body>
<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Mike</p>
  <p>This is a test: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**div.css**

```
#Header {

background:#000;
height:100px
}
#header {
    color: white
}
```

Comment: There can be only one `<body>` element in a document - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body). Also, `<a href="<a href="` is not valid.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: What's invalid about it? Please explain. I know it is invalid, since I asked the community for help.

Comment: Thanks, Showdev. I'm looking into it.

Comment: That's just a start. You might find an [HTML validator service](http://validator.w3.org/) helpful.

Comment: where exactly is the black rectangular box you're trying to achieve? around the div with #header id? around the text "The Header"?

Comment: Run it through any validator and you'll see the issues. A couple: you have multiple body elements, with code outside of both, your IDs have spaces, and your link syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the valid version of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>CSS Tutorial 1</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>We are creating this page to see how to make a better looking website.</p>
    <p>We are creating this page to see how to make a better looking website.</p>

    <div id="header">This is a paragraph</div>

    <div class="column-2">
        <h1>The Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="column-2">This is a basic CSS<br><br> Tokyo<br></div>

    <div class="column-3">
        <h1><a href="<a href="http://gymforgeeks.userecho.com">This is GymForGeeks</h1>
        <p>This is just a sample page using CSS.</p>
        <p>Yet another sample text content.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">Copyright Queensborough</div>

    <footer>
        <p>Posted by: Mike</p>
        <p>This is a test: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">someone@example.com</a>.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Some things you should know:

- you should not have multiple elements with the same id
- any HTML page can only have 1 `body` element
- id must be string and should not contain spaces. e.g. `column-3`
- any HTML tag (`p`, `div`, `footer`, `span`, ..) must be inside `<body></body>` tag
- use classes if you want to apply same style to multiple elements

In order to make your elements appear in columns you will need to use a grid framework (getbootstrap.com, 960.gs, ..) or create your custom CSS that will order your elements:

e.g. style.css:

```
.column-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.column-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

This is only an example. You will need to do some digging until you get to your desired grid.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I really find your answer useful. Just a question, how come when I preview it, it doesn't actually show up in columns?

Comment: Well you need to add CSS style to those classes so that they behave like columns. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

You have to close an opened div with only `</div>` not `</div id="header">`

CSS is is casesensitive so you have to use #header not #Header

And you can combine those two definitions:

```
#header {
background:#000;
height:100px;
color: white;
}
```

Hope i could help a little.

I cleaned up your mess a little further: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qacAg

Explanation:

- after you closed the `</head>` you have to open a `<body>`
- this is how a working link looks like: `<a href="www.target.com">TEXT</a>`
- you should only use id's for unique areas or divs not multiple times - use classes instead  `<div class="THECLASS">THE CONTENT</div>`
- dont use spaces in classes or id names it will create multiple classes

Answer (score 2):

Your code is  totally wrong:

1) body is the starting element, after /head, and that is the last element before /html and use it only once.

2) When you close the div, no need to add id.

3) Id should be one string

4) You use a href badly

5) You do not close your css

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/7uggw2x6/1/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
....
</head>

<body>

<p>We are creating this page to see how to make a better looking website.</p>

<p>We are creating this page to see how to make a better looking website.</p>

<div id="header">This is a paragraph</div>

<div id="column_1"><h1>The Header</h1></div>

<div id="column_2">This is a basic CSS<br><br>Tokyo<br></div>

<div id="column_3">
    <h1><a href="http://gymforgeeks.userecho.com">This is GymForGeeks</a></h1>
 <p>This is just a sample page using CSS.</p>
 <p>Yet another sample text content.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">Copyright Queensborough</div>
<footer>
    <p>Posted by: Mike</p>
    <p>This is a test: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">someone@example.com</a>./p>
 </footer>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background:#000;
    height:100px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use in your **CSS-File** following style:

```
#header {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 100px; 
}
```

You can learn the Basic of HTML and CSS at [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com).

I hope I could solve your problem.

Regards
t.koelpin

Answer (score 1):

you have a few problems. The structure of your html is incorrect. the footer element goes inside
the body tag. You have to have a closing tag for your divs and your content goes in the middle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="div.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>CSS Tutorial 1</title>
    <!-- this section is for loading scripts, css and metadata -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- this section is for content -->    
    <div class='header'>
        Header text
    </div>
    <footer>
       <!-- footer tags are HTML5 Tags and should be used with the HTML5 doctype -->
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The css

```
#header {
    background:#000;
    height:100px;
    color: white;
   }
```